# Webview SSL Certification error untrusted

Tags: java, android, ssl, webview

I am facing a problem in my android app.
when i am trying to load a url in my webview it gives me ssl error untrusted certificate.

The url opens on mobile and pc without any problem but on my webview it wont. the url has oauth2 login confimration...

I've tried using onReceivedSslError and give it `handler.proceed()` and it works..but this is unsafe since it bypass all the ssl security and google play store won't let you publish your app with this line of code.

Please need help guys!! thanks

Comment: You need to implement certificate pinning in your application. https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e

Comment: hello @PedroOliveira i've already implemented the pinning certificate between the app and the server.. but i am trying to reach an open api for bank url... what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Certificate certificate;
  CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
    certificate = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    caInput.close();

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

add the onReceivedSslError as below. check the certificate that you have in raw file with the certificate that the url uses so you sould verify it using`cert.verify`

```
 @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

            SslCertificate sslCertificate = error.getCertificate();
            Certificate cert = getX509Certificate(sslCertificate);
            if (cert != null && certificate != null){
                try {
                    cert.verify(certificate.getPublicKey());
                    handler.proceed();
                } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchProviderException | SignatureException e) {
                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                    handler.cancel();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            }
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
```

add the piece of code function that generates the certificate as shown below

```
private Certificate getX509Certificate(SslCertificate sslCertificate) {
    Bundle bundle = SslCertificate.saveState(sslCertificate);
    byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate");
    if (bytes == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            return certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code to invoke SslErrorHandler.proceed() whenever the certificate presented by the server meets your expectations, and invoke SslErrorHandler.cancel() otherwise. An email alert containing the affected app(s) and class(es) has been sent to your developer account address.

This is what google security alert will show if you upload your app with onReceivedSslError and use handler.proceed without checking the certificate.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the SSL [certificate chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust) was broken. You can quickly test such issues with [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) or more intermediate with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). But please do not ask me how this can happen.

After reinstalling the SSL certificate, all errors regarding the "untrusted SSL certificate in WebView whatsoever" disappeared finally. I also **removed the @Override for onReceivedSslError(...) and got rid of handler.proceed()**, and é voila my app was not rejected by Google Play Store (again).